# Joomla 1.5 install without domain

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

So, I installed a new joomla 1.523 (via Fantastico) on my server, but event though I have the domain name set, I haven't registered it yet. Now I need to acess joomla, and I can't.

I already did this with a Moodle server, and I know I had to change a config file to set the url to the IP. So basically I should acess it with:

http://190.190.190.190/~user

(This ip doesen't exist, just making an example).

But I always get an error trying to acess it, even though I get redirected to:

http://190.190.190.190/~user/installation/index.php

Anyone know what I need to change to get this to work?

(I tried messing around with the configuration.php file in the root of my server, but there is nothing there like a url path variable to change, I think)

Comment: what error are you getting? after installing Joomla, the installation folders needs to be removed (or moved or renamed), otherwise any access will be redirected there.

Comment: Woah, that was surprisingly easy. It fixed my problem. Do a answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing Joomla, the installation folder needs to be removed (or moved, or renamed), otherwise any access will be redirected there.